# in fastapi sqlalchemy session, list append is not working

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi

when i update my serverdata by using session db,

```
db_post = deb.query(models.Post).filter(models.Post.id === post.id).first()
db_post.likes.append(email)
setattr(db_post,"likes",db_post_likes)
db.add(db_post)
db.commit()
db.refresh(db_post)
return db_post
```

then it is not updated db_post_likes,
but when i use below code it works with out append

```
db_post = deb.query(models.Post).filter(models.Post.id === post.id).first()
setattr(db_post,"likes",db_post_likes + [email])
db.add(db_post)
db.commit()
db.refresh(db_post)
return db_post
```

the problem is append can be skipped upper code, but remove is also problem

how can i fix this?

Comment: Remove the `setattr(…)` in the first snippet and see if it works any better.

Comment: @GrodThompson Oh i see... i will try that. Thanks

Comment: It doesnt work.. but thanks for reply..

Answer (score 1):

now i know.

list.append or list.remove not return event.
so sqlalchemy session can not detect changed

so sqlalchemy recommned to use MutableList

and now it works